# Можно ли вставлять void функцию внутри другой void функции?

Tags: c#

Как подставить void функции с разным количеством параметров в данный кусок кода?

```
void RunTransaction(void Function(...)) 
{
    using (var manager = new NHibernateManager())
    {
        var session = manager.GetSession();
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Function();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что значит вставить void-функции? Их вызовы? Ну вы можете написать там, например, `Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!")`

Comment: @АндрейNOP не в этом дело. Например, в качестве параметров функции с транзакцией я передаю функцию Edit(NewsItemEditViewModel editModel , HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage) или же Add(NewsItemAddViewModel newsModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage, string UserId) и она себе отрабатывает и гуд.

Comment: Отлично, в чем вопрос?

Comment: @АндрейNOP как запихивать в качестве параметров функцию(1 вопрос), как запихивать функции с разными параметрами в качестве параметра функции транзакции(та самая, что c using начинается).

Comment: @АндрейNOP трабла в том что делегаты могут принимать только функции с идентичными сигнатурами.

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример желаемой «подстановки» функций и укажите с какими проблемами/ошибками Вы столкнулись.

Comment: @defaultlocale вот скрин , который пояснит, какую магию я хочу воплотить http://priscree.ru/img/35fa426bf2127c.png

Comment: Если нужен скрин, то его нужно добавить в сам вопрос (под текстом вопроса есть кнопка «править»).

Comment: @AshenOne такие вещи надо писать текстом, а не скринами

Comment: как вы объявляете одну ф-ию внутри списка параметров другой `void RunTransaction(void Function(...))`, чёрт побери ?)

Comment: @Alias кажется, именно в этом его вопрос и заключается

Answer (score 4):

Нужная вам конструкция в языке C# и в .NET вообще называется "делегат".

Вы можете объявить свой тип делегата:

```
public delegate void TransactionParticipant();
```

Или же можно воспользоваться стандартным `System.Action` (без параметров доступен начиная с .NET 3.5)

Делегаты работают как вы и хотели:

```
public void RunTransaction(Action fn) 
{
   // ...
   fn();
   // ...
}
```

Передать в такой делегат функцию `void Edit(NewsItemEditViewModel editModel, HttpPostedFileBase uploadedImage)` напрямую нельзя, потому что списки параметров не совпадают (да и просто подумайте - откуда внутри `ExecuteInTransaction` возьмутся значения для параметров?) Но всегда можно воспользоваться лямбдой (она же замыкание):

```
RunTransaction(() => Edit(editModel, uploadedImage));
```

PS скорее всего, вам внутри вашей функции понадобится как минимум переменная `session`. Вам ее нужно будет сделать параметром делегата:

```
public delegate void TransactionParticipant(NHibernateSession session);

fn(session);

RunTransaction(s => Edit(s, editModel, uploadedImage));
```

Также можно воспользоваться обобщенным вариантом `System.Action` - `System.Action<NHibernateSession>`.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx

```
void RunTransaction(System.Action anAction)
{
  //...
  anAction();
  //...
}

void SomeMethod()
{
}

RunTransaction(SomeMethod);
RunTransaction(() => { /* any code */ });
```

Answer (score -1):

судя по скриншоту -- вы путаете определение функции с её вызовом;

ключевое слово `void` используется только в определении функции, и указывает что **она не возвращает значение**, только выполняет своё тело.

Поэтому:

1. указать, как вы выразились, *void функцию* **в качестве параметра** какой-либо другой функции **нельзя** ни при определении, ни при вызове; также нельзя присваивать её какой-либо переменной(кроме указателя...), т.к. с т.з. компилятора там присваивать просто нечего!
2. допустимость вызова *void функции* **из тела** любой др.функции, как и из произвольного места программы, определяется только её областью видимости, т.е. **в принципе можно** :)

Ваша магия могла бы выглядеть так:

```
void RunTransaction()//тут указывать параметром void_функцию незачем
{
  using (var manager = new NHibernateManager())
  {
    var session = manager.GetSession();
    using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
      Function();//!ф-ия будет вызываться просто если её "видно"
      transaction.Commit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: хэй, минусильщик -- чего не так?)

Comment: Например то, что передать в качестве параметра можно **любую** функцию

Comment: @Grundy  хмм, т.е. например так `void f(int c){...}  void  F(){...}  f(F());//сработает!?` по вашему??

Comment: Конечно нет, как минимум `f` в параметрах должна принимать функцию, а не `int`. Именно об этом речь в вопросе: `f(Action a){...} void F(){...} f(F);`

Comment: Кстати то, что ты привел в качестве примере это **не** передача функции. Это передача **результата вызова** функции. Что несколько разные вещи.

Comment: @Grundy ага, и именно эту "магию" зачем-то хотел вопрошающий в исходном вопросе -- прошу заметить, употребляя глагол "запихивать":)) я интерпритирую это именно так))   Pavel Mayorov предложил решением исп-ие делегатов... но автор ответ не принял и не прокомментировал пока-что (а зря).